# Add scound Linux OS dual with Centos 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, grub2, dd

I have been trying to add a second OS  Ubuntu 16.04.2, actually  I have installed Centos 7 as primary os.

I download the ISO file of Ubuntu and  load it to USB drive using the DD.
I tried to boot from the USB using the grub2 terminal without success.

Now I am trying to load the ISO from my hard drive from my `/home/<username>/download/`.
I tried to add a new entry in the grub2 menu by editing the
`/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
    menuentry "Ubuntu 16.04.2 ISO" {
        set isofile="/home/usern/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile  noprompt noeject
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
    }
```

finally here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk label type: gpt

 #####    Start End    Size   Type      Name

 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition

 2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic 

 3      2508800   1465147391  697.5G  Linux LVM
```

Can anyone help or guide me on how to install Ubuntu in dual boot?

Comment: Are you able to boot from the Flash Drive using the bios or boot menu of the system itself?

Comment: no not able to boot form any wehre

Answer (score 0):

According to your setup, you are using LVM for partition management. Therefore the `/home` directory is not accessible without unlocking the LVM volume group (VG) and it will not be easy to load the ISO file without this.

It may be possible to load the ISO but it will be complicated. Please try to boot from USB using BIOS startup options (press a system-specific key before the boot loader is loading, sometimes F1 or F12 or Esc to select the boot device - your USB drive!).

Comment: In my experience installing a second Linux on an LVM system is a great source of trouble, sometimes not possible, depending on the installation system of the second Linux.

Comment: oh  OK and what system do recommend ?

Comment: Not sure, because I have not managed to do this, either. You would need a Linux variant that can use an existing LVM volume during installation (maybe someone else knows a suitable one?). Sometimes this is possible with a trick (e.g. mount the LV in a shell during install). The easiest would be to re-install CentOS without LVM and leave a partition for a(ny) second OS. However, you may not want to do so because if you wish to keep data and config you would need to backup (at least) `/home` to an external disk. I will think some more. Please let me know whether you would consider a re-install.

Comment: No way for me to boot from USB or any thing. All that I have tried was not successful ....

Comment: Is there a way to delete everything and start over ?

Comment: You could do whatever you did when you installed CentOS in the first place. During installation select manual disk/partition management and create a layout without LVM. In order to find out what partition sizes you need type `df` in your current system. Look at the used size of `/` root (leave space for new files, e.g. current usage plus 100%). During installation delete partition 3 (that deletes all of your files and settings, make a backup if you need them!) and re-use partitions 1 and 2 as before (enter this manually). Leave space for a 2nd OS (e.g. 20-30G). Rest goes to `/home`.